# What to do with answer accusing OP of being a criminal performing scams?

Tags: discussion, flags

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33008823/2200659) answer to a the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904118/issue-with-paypal-ipn-update-code:

> I suspect that your website has detected that your domain name is registered to a non-existent address and that you are trying to scam people out of money unlawfully ..... just a hunch.

I have no knowledge of the subject matter of the question, but it seems like the answer accuses the OP of being a criminal and a scammer. What to do with such an answer? Flag it? As what? Ignore it? Downvote it?

Or am I just misunderstanding this because I know nothing about PayPal and IPN?

**EDIT:** It has been suggested that I should flag it as *not an answer* because it does not answer the question. OK, that might be true. But isn't the fact that it accuses another user of being a criminal a more serious thing that should be handled? Would that be OK if it had just been a comment instead?

**EDIT 2:** The answer has disappeared without any intervention from me. The meta effect was here. As pointed out in comments, it seems that the person who asked the question is in fact involved with a scam. Is it OK to ask for help with your scamming on SO (given that the question is about actual programming)?

Comment: It's not a real answer so I suppose it should be flagged as such. The answer's author is right though, the whole thing looks really fishy (and I'm not talking about the catastrophically unsafe PHP code). The address doesn't exist, and it looks like a scam in preparation. Can't think of an innocent explanation. I sent an E-Mail to Devon council asking them to look into it.

Comment: Ah, there is a back story: http://parking-prankster.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/devon-parking-agency-scam.html

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the detective work! I guess the accusation was valid then.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Nice find ;)

Comment: @Pekka웃 http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?s=ad648766ebeffab5d7f8fbe1ce4f2fde&p=69295637 - see the post timed 8th Oct 15, 12:07 AM

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but is `everything works apart from the "Update" section` really a clear problem statement?

Comment: @TZHX nope. It is as atrocious as everything else about the question

Comment: The website has been taken down

Comment: Probably taken down to protect against the attacks it's prone to. I think the "Impact Team" could well be interested!

Comment: If nothing else, they're doing a great service to helping people SQLInjection the living F~&k out of their system. "Yes my first name really is `1';update 'parkingtickets' set 'paid'='1'` - why do you ask?"

Comment: @Pekka웃 this is not so much a backsory - as a breaking story. Going on right now! http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=5337579&page=3#topofpage local police and press apparently involved and this user has admitted they are behind the scam

Comment: @Jamiec yay! How cool is that!

Comment: The OP is a scumbag and should be banned.  ... not this OP, I mean the OP of the other question, who is a scammer.  This op, well, I guess he's okay, let him stay.

Comment: Also, it looks like [they've seen this question as well](http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?s=69dfb2fcee6291db542128a3c261a790&t=5337579&page=4#post69299229)

Comment: @Will If you only knew about my evil plans...

Comment: @TinyGiant So they know that we know? And we know that they know? And they know that we know that they know?

Comment: Well, I don't know if they know that we know that they know

Comment: Well, now I do know that [they know that we know that they know](http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?s=69dfb2fcee6291db542128a3c261a790&t=5337579&page=4#post69301202)

Comment: The Ulbricht Silk Road post comes to mind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19143265/895245

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's an answer to the question, in that it's explaining why the OP is having the problem that he's having.  So what should you do?  Feel free to vote on the answer based on it's accuracy/quality, if you're qualified to judge whether it is a technically correct or incorrect answer.

The question, on the other hand, is full of problems.  The most significant of which is that it just dumps some code and says that it doesn't work with no explanation of what the specific problem is, what the errors are, etc.  I'm also not an expert in that field, but it looks like the code isn't a very good MCVE, in that it both appears to be missing important information to replicate the problem and containing a fair bit of irrelevant information.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to flag the answer was not so much its technical quality, but rather that it was rude (to say the least) to accuse someone of being a criminal. Now it seems like the accusation was in fact true, but I think it still could be argued that an accusation like that should not be handled in an answer but in a flag with a message to moderators or something. Just accusing each other of crimes publicly doesn't give a nice atmosphere.

Comment: @Anders If someone is being handcuffed by the police and asks you what's going on, and you tell them that it looks like they're being arrested, then you are neither accusing them of anything nor are you being rude.  You're providing the answer to their question and informing them that someone *else* appears to be accusing them of doing something wrong, which is the only valid answer to the question that they asked.  Now if you feel that this answer is wrong (or at least provides insufficient evidence to demonstrate that it's correct) then you're free to act accordingly (through voting).

Comment: Thank you. That comment was what I was trying to get at. I read the answer as the poster accusing OP of being a criminal, but it should be read as PayPal suspecting him of being a criminal. Thank you for the nice metahpor. :-)

Comment: "and that you are trying to scam people out of money unlawfully" _is_ a speculative accusation unrelated to the technical content. The rest is a factual potential answer. Editing would be the correct move here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell does it still count as a speculative accusation if we read the answer as "your website has detected ... that you are trying to scam people out of money unlawfully"?

Comment: Perhaps not, @JanDvorak, but I'd definitely want to see some explanation as to how and why a website had made that determination.

Answer (score 13):

It could be parsed as a guess as to what the website thinks the user doing and why it is designed to characterize errors that way, or as an accusation as to what the answerer thinks the user is doing.

I would recommend all criminals post their coding problems on SO, along with their GPS coordinates and a selfie (following guidelines as for a [passport photo](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/photos/photo-examples.html)). This will help SO provide the most value to the community, certain members of which will be glad to make a house call for properly constructed questions.

Answer (score -12):

Downvote and flag it as *not an answer*.

Comment: Care to explain why? I guess the first sentence is sort of an answer? Should it only be flagged because it is not an answer, and not because it is accusing another user of being criminal (sounds more serious to me)?

Comment: Because it doesn't attempt to answer the question. I suppose you could flag it as rude/abusive, but imho that would be an overreaction.

Comment: Well, it is actually an answer and quite possibly an accurate one as well.  Probably would read better if it said "I suspect that PayPal has detected ...".  Edited.

Comment: Agreed there (with Hans), the question is asking why there is a problem - being blocked as a (potential) scammer by the service you're trying to invoke is a pretty solid problem to have and thus an answer. To a terrible question. Downvote the question, not the answer.

Comment: @Gimby the question says "everything works on this code apart from the "Update" section", it's a bad question and it should have been closed. The user who posted that answer did some internet detective work, and may or may not be correct. Either way, an answer to a SO post is not the place to report such things. They should be reported to the authorities if one is concerned about a possible scam.

Comment: But there is no hint in there at all that it is any kind of "report". It is an honest answer with a bit of an unfortunate and unnecessary finger pointing. I don't think I would have been able to resist giving a human response either.